# Storage symlink path on nginx is not working the way it should

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, laravel-5.8

this is my first time uploading laravel on nginx server, there is a weird behavior (at least for me) that I am seeing that the storage symlink path is not working the like it normally does on apache that

> domain.com/storage/filename.jpg  (on apache)

but now that I am on nginx above path is going 404 instead this path is accessible

> domain.com/storage/app/public/filename.jpg

Is this a normal behaviour for NGINX Laravel combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you still have to symlink you storage directory by using the command:
`php artisan storage:link`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk